Evaluating $\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{(a - b \sin t)^2 + 1} \, dt $; connections to elliptic integrals?
I am investigating the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \sqrt{(a - b \sin t)^2 + 1} \, dt$$
where $a > 0$ and $b>0$. This integral arises in a context involving periodic functions, and I suspect it has a connection to elliptic integrals due to its structure.
When we have $a=0$, for specific integer values of $b$ the integral is $4 \, \text{EllipticE}(-b^2)$, and for general b it is $2 \left(\text{EllipticE}(-b^2) + \sqrt{1 + b^2} \, \text{EllipticE}\left(\frac{b^2}{1 + b^2}\right)\right).$
But even for simple special cases like $a=1,b=1$ and $a=1,b=2$ CAS is not helping. I tried some trig transformations without any success.
Has this integral or a closely related one been evaluated in mathematical literature, or is it too challenging at this moment?
By the way, I have also posted this question in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/5016795/1322804 to broaden the audience.
Thanks

Avoid such simultaneous crosspost, better delete one of the two.

Maple v 2024.2 for  integer a, b in the range 1..5 returns answers with EllipticE, EllipticK and EllipticPi, presumably for higher integers also.

That this integral is elliptic is seen by changing
$\sin t=x$. Then it becomes
$$\int\sqrt{\frac{(a-bx)^2+1}{1-x^2}}dx,$$
and this is an elliptic integral since the Riemann surface of the integrand is of genus $1$. Maple actually expresses it in terms of the standard elliptic integrals, but there are very many cases, depending on $a$ and $b$, more precisely on the location of
the roots of the polynomial in the numerator with respect to $\pm1$. For some values of $a,b$ the expression is too long to be reproduced here.
